# Choosing two balls when there are not enough balls of a given colour

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have $4$ balls in a bag, $3$ of them are red and $1$ is blue. We would take two balls at random. What is the probability of taking out:

1. two same colours.
2. two different colours.

I did as following; to have same colour: 
$$\frac{{3\choose 2}+{1\choose 1}}{{4\choose 2}}\approx0.66$$
to be different colour: 
$$1-\frac{{3\choose 2}+{1\choose 1}}{{4\choose 2}}\approx0.33$$
Is this correct? I did this intuitively as ${1\choose 2}=0$ means you can not choose two balls from 1 ball left. Am I correct in this justification?

Comment: What is your logic behind using $3\choose 2$? You should be doing it as$${\text{how many balls in total}}\choose{\text{how many fit the colour you want}}$$

Comment: What does the title mean?  "not enough" for what?   Where does the $\binom 11$ come from?

Comment: @lulu I thin OP's thoughts were that $1\choose 1$ represents there being $1$ blue ball, and somehow "choosing" that. The "not enough" part, I am not sure

Comment: Note:  the numbers here are so small that there is no reason at all not to simply write out all the cases.  That would, at least, let you check your answers.

Comment: @JohnDoe  It is not possible to choose two blue balls is there is only one, which is why $\binom{1}{2} = 0$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig but there are 4 balls in total, and we never have to pick out more than $2$.

Comment: There is only one favorable case, namely picking two of the three red balls.

Comment: @lulu by not enough I meant where there is one blue ball and you want to pick 2. How does one proceed in such cases?

Comment: @William you cannot pick $2$ blue balls in this case. So you do not consider this as a possibility. When they as for how many ways to pick $2$ of the same colour, all this means is how many ways to pick $2$ reds

Comment: The only "same color" case is "two reds", as "two blues" is impossible.  If you want to stick with the formula, just note that $\binom 12=0$.

Comment: so we have $$\frac{{3\choose 2}+{1\choose 2}}{{4\choose 2}}=1/2$$ ? is this not counter intuitive? we have 50-50 chance while there are 3 reds and 1 blue.

Comment: This is where writing out the cases is a good idea.  There are only $6$ cases!!  Just number the red ones, so you have $\{R_1,R_2,R_3,B\}$ and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose we have four balls in a bag, three of them are red and one is blue.  We draw two balls at random. What is the probability of selecting two balls of the same color?

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select to select two of the four balls.

The favorable cases are selecting two of the three red balls, which can be done in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, or two blue balls, which is impossible since there is only one blue ball.  Hence, the probability that two balls of the same color are obtained is 
$$\Pr(\text{two balls of the same color}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{4}{2}}$$
If you want to make clear that you considered the possibility of selecting two blue balls, you can write the answer in the form 
$$\Pr(\text{two balls of the same color}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{2} + \dbinom{1}{2}}{\dbinom{4}{2}}$$
which is equal to the previous result since $\binom{1}{2} = 0$.

> Suppose we have four balls in a bag, three of them are red and one is blue.  We draw two balls at random. What is the probability of selecting two balls of different colors?

The denominator is the same as above.

The favorable cases are those in which we select one of the three red balls and the only blue ball, so the probability is 
$$\Pr(\text{two balls of different colors}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{1}{1}}{\dbinom{4}{2}}$$

**Check:** There are only two possibilities.  Either the selected balls are the same color or they are different colors.  Therefore, the two probabilities that we have calculated should add to $1$, as you can verify.

Comment: for the different colour we can write $1-\frac{{3\choose 2}+{1\choose 2}}{{4\choose 2}}$ which is same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(a,b)$ be the probability of choosing a ball with colour $a$ followed by a ball of colour $b$. I am going to assume that the two balls are taken out at one after the other without replacement. Then

$P(\text{red}, \text{red}) = \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(\text{red}, \text{blue}) = \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(\text{blue}, \text{red}) = \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{3}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(\text{blue}, \text{blue}) = 0$

I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any formulation for the generalised case of this game suppose for example we have $x$ number of red, $y$ number of blue and additionally $z$ number of green, how do we write $P(a,b)$ in generalised form?